# shorthand way to create dictionary key if it does not exist

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of zoo animals. I want to put it into the dictionary in a nested dictionary but get a KeyError because that particular species has not been added to the dictionary.

```
def add_to_world(self, species, name, zone = 'retreat'):
    self.object_attr[species][name] = {'zone' : zone}
```

Is there a shortcut to checking if that species is in the dictionary and create it if it is not or do i have to do it the long way and manually check if that species has been added?

Comment: Is a species likely to have more than one name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def add_to_world(self, species, name, zone = 'retreat'):
    self.object_attr.setdefault(species, {})[name] = {'zone' : zone}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `SyntaxError` error when trying `print {}.setdefault('species', {})['name'] = {'zone' : 'thezone'}`. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Assignment is not an expression in Python and cannot be used in a `print` statement.

Comment: That is to say, you have to do something like `d ={}; d.setdefault('species', {})['name'] = {'zone': 'thezone'}; print d`

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of using defaultdict with a dictionary as a value.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d["species"]["name"] = {"zone": "1"}
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'species': {'name': {'zone': '1'}}})
>>>
```

If you want further nesting you'll need to make a function to return *defaultdict(dict)*.

```
def nested_defaultdict():
    return defaultdict(dict)

# Then you can use a dictionary nested to 3 levels
d2 = defaultdict(nested_defaultdict)
d2["species"]["name"]["zone"] = 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Autovivification of dictionary values can be performed by [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: Just ugly on print: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02379DF0>, {'2013-11-29': defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'USG': D...

Comment: is there a relatively non-obscure equivalent of that word en espanol?